# How to update crontab in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, whenever

I am using `whenever` gem for cronjobs. To update crontab locally I do

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

I want to know how to update cron-tab on heroku.

Another question is that I am using free-tier of heroku.Is paid account needed for that or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the crontab on heroku, you have to use something like the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

The reason why you can't use the crontab is that heroku uses an ephemeral file system. So, if you run a command to change the crontab (with `heroku run whenever --update-crontab` for example), heroku would start a dyno, change its crontab locally, then throw the dyno away. So your changes would not be persistent.

You can use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) with a free account, you just need to write your code as rake tasks, then add the corresponding rake commands in the scheduler config page.

Comment: Meanz whenever gem is useless?

Comment: On heroku I'm afraid it is useless.

Comment: Heroku Scheduler user one-off dyno andI read that "Any time spent executing a one-off dyno will contribute to usage and will be charged just like any other dyno."

Comment: If your total usage (web + scheduler) fits in the free tier then you are fine. I believe heroku gives you 18 free hours a day, if you go beyond that on a free dyno they'll put your app to sleep for a while.